# Convert Java String into Date format

Tags: string, simpledateformat

I'm stuggling to convert String 'Tue Jan 01 01:01:00 GMT 2013' into a date format.
I tried to use simple date class, but it didn't succeed.

```
String st=list[1];
Date start = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(list[1]);
```

Maybe someone can find my mistake or recommend something else.
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy")
```

and I would perhaps check [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Beware also that `SimpleDateFormat` isn' thread-safe and you may prefer to use the [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace `zzz`with `Z`